# How to align baseline of one view to top of another

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to do like this where green icon is aligned by its baseline to top of this white card

[image]

In my case i can just align top part of green icon to top part of white card. layout_marginTop for green icon doen't allow to move it to top in this case.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.wearable.view.CardFrame
        android:id="@+id/card_home"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TEXT"
            android:textColor="@color/black"/>
    </android.support.wearable.view.CardFrame>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/menu"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/card_home"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/card_home"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with negativ margin-top

```
   <ImageView
       ...
       android:layout_marginTop="-30dp"
       .../>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. Try like this, the trick is to replace marginBottom in your    `<ImageView>` with marginTop and assign to it a negative value, for example:

```
  <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/card_home"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="#FF00FFFF"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TEXT"
                android:textColor="#ff000000"/>
        </FrameLayout>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/abc_btn_check_to_on_mtrl_015"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/card_home"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/card_home"
            android:layout_marginTop="-15dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**Notice the last line:  `android:layout_marginTop="-15dp"`**

This gives me something like this: 
[image]